# Align a layout top of a image that is centered

Tags: android

I have a relative layout, inside of it is a ImageView that is centered in its parent.

I want to add a share up to the image. If I put this attribute         `android:layout_alignTop="@+id/myImage"` the button will appear over the image. I want to be upper than this.

Comment: you can use android:layout_above="@+id/myImage"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
android:layout_below="@+id/shareId"
```

in your `<ImageView>` tag. Or

```
android:layout_above="@+id/myImage"
```

in your share's `View` tag depending on what works better for you. If this doesn't fix it then please post the xml and a picture of what you want/have if possible.

[RelativeLayout Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) shows the different properties that can be used.

Comment: Yes , It works, I will accept the answer as soon as this will be possible

Comment: Ok, glad it works for you. Also, I just edited with a link to the docs so you can see everything that is available for that `ViewGroup`.